# How to use the singular they in a sentence between a person and a group?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

*Example:*

> A philosophy student has to go before a panel of judges and debate **his** topic.

if I make it:

> A philosophy student has to go before a panel of judges and debate **their** topic.

The reader isn't sure if I'm talking about the student's topic or the judges' topic.

*Another example:*

> These people will then teach the philosophy student taking into account **his** background of experience.

if I make it:

> These people will then teach the philosophy student taking into account **their** background of experience.

The reader isn't sure if I'm talking about the student's background or these people background.

What to do in these types of situations?

Comment: It's no more ambiguous that *"A philosophy student has to go before an examiner and debate his topic."* Get rid of it in the same way you would get rid of the ambiguity in that sentence. You could, for example, say *"A philosophy student has to debate his topic before an examiner."*

Comment: @PeterShor If you don't mind me asking, how would you solve the ambiguity in that sentence?

Comment: @user405662 I find that brackets make the whole thing look amateurish...

Comment: I edited my comment to give one way to remove the ambiguity. For your second sentence you can fix it by: *These people will then teach the philosophy student taking into account the student's background.* (*background of experience* sounds wrong in English; you'd generally just say *background* or *experience*). But because I don't understand the full context of your sentences, there may be better ways.

Comment: @PeterShor Pretty underwhelming solution to be honest, particularly if one has used the word student in the previous sentences and now would prefer not to repeat it. But perhaps this is one of the issues with trying to make everything into a gender neutral pronoun. Traditionally using he/his/him would make this pretty simple:  **These people will then teach him taking into account his background.**

Comment: ... But it doesn't resolve 'The professor will then teach him taking into account his background.' _Singular they_ and _generic his_ both have drawbacks.

Comment: 1. *A philosophy student has to debate their topic before a panel of judges.*

Comment: 2. *Taking into account the philosophy student's background of experience, these people will then design an individualized curriculum.*

Answer (score 1):

Deletion of "go" and 'pronoun shifting' will do the job.

> A philosophy student has to debate his topic before a panel of judges.
>
> A philosophy student has to debate their topic before a panel of
> judges.
>
> Taking into account the philosophy student's background of experience,
> these people will teach him.
>
> Taking into account their background of experience, these people will
> teach him.